# Is there a way in "Chrome" to group tabs like there is in Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way in "Chrome" to group tabs like there is in Firefox? If not, is there an extension available that replicates this behaviour?

Comment: Looking for the same, in '18.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the [Tabs Saver](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-saver/kmabfaomlcjlnplkoflgenkmmpilmead?hl=en-US) Chrome Extension. Although it's not as integrated as Firefox' solution, it may work for you.